# What .Net API should i use to know the filename and path that i recently downloaded to windows temp folder?

Tags: c#, .net, api, temp

Well, i want to know the methods or any API that can return me the filename and the path of the recently downloaded file to windows temp folder. I tried `Fileinfo` but its not exactly what i wanted. So, is there anyway to achieve what i want?

EDIT:
i think i did mentioned temp folder which is `c:\\Users\\aneal\\appdata\\Local\\Temp` . The purpose is to copy the temp files like streaming videos to another location before it gets removed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the filename of the recently downloaded file, you'll have to write some logic for capturing that. The temporary directory can be found using something like:

```
System.IO.Path.GetTempPath();
```

or

```
System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache);
```

Comment: Maybe, except you definitely don't want `MyDocuments`. If I understand the question, you want `InternetCache`.

Comment: Good point, I've updated the enum to use InternetCache instead.